# Docker container unreachable

Tags: docker, ubuntu, flask

I have a dockerised flask app with some files mentioned below

[Docker File](https://pastebin.com/3BvkHzn3), [app.py](https://pastebin.com/NrkefGVz)

I am using the below command to build and run the container

```
# Create Virtual Network
$ sudo docker network create network_1

# Create Container
$ sudo docker build -t form_ocr:latest .
$ sudo docker run -d -p 6001:5000 --net network_1 --name form_ocr form_ocr
```

After creating the virtual network and container following IP is assigned to them

> Network network_1 IP: 172.18.0.1
>
> Container form_ocr internal IP: 172.18.0.2

So the container is up and running and from host it should accessible at this path `0.0.0.0:6001` but it's not, I did some troubleshooting on the running container as mentioned below

Output of `netstat` command (within the container)

```
$ netstat -nltp
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:46011        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.5:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3
```

Output of `docker ps` command

```
$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID     IMAGE         COMMAND            CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
3c3f454ab515     form_ocr     "python3 app.py"    About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:6001->5000/tcp     form_ocr
```

System host file `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       arush-pc
...
```

I have the following doubts

Q1 Why container listening to `127.0.0.5` when address `0.0.0.0` is mentioned in `app.py` ?

Q1 If the container is listening to address `127.0.0.5:5000` then what does `127.0.0.11:46011` address refers to ?

I am a beginner in docker any comment would be very helpful

[Minimal Code](https://filebin.net/ik70xuem69c54i4v)

Comment: All of the IP addresses you list are implementation details; they'll change when you restart the containers, and you should completely ignore them.  With that `docker run -p` option, if the `app.py` says it's listening on `0.0.0.0:5000`, then the container should be reachable at `http://localhost:6001`.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve], with the relevant source code (in the question itself, not behind a link) and the actual error you're getting trying to connect?

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze I have created the minimal code (link in the post) which runs fine because it is listening at `0.0.0.0:5000` as expected (checked from within container using `netstat -nltp` command) but why my main code is listening at `127.0.0.5:5000`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual code, not a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your container local server to run on host `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.
This way you'll map all the interfaces that will for sure intercept any request to the port `5000`.

Depending on the server you're using you'll do the following:

---

for `uvicorn` you'll have something similar to this

`uvicorn --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000  main:app`

---

for `gunicorn` it'll be something like this

`gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 main:app`